# Why can I not access the google-storage url from inside Docker with moviepy?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, moviepy

I have a docker instance setup from which I am using moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip to edit urls that come from a google cloud instance.

Locally, I have no problem doing this at all and can run:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
vfc = VideoFileClip('https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<mp4 name>')
...
```

However, in the docker instance, I am having problems accessing the file via moviepy, with the error:

`Failed to resolve hostname storage.googleapis.com: Name or service not known`

In the same python shell, i can run:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<mp4 name>', '/tmp/file.mp4')
```

And it works perfectly. Any idea what's going wrong?

`Python Version`: Python 3.7.3
`Moviepy Version`: moviepy==0.2.3.5
`Platform Name`: Alpine
`Platform Version`: Linux fe434704cf18 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 Linux

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:4.1-alpine as ffmpeg

FROM python:3.7-alpine3.8

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache --update \
        libgcc \
        libstdc++ \
        curl \
        ca-certificates \
        libcrypto1.0 \
        libssl1.0 \
        libgomp \
        bash \
        expat \
        git \
        openblas \
        musl \
        ffmpeg \
        ghostscript \
        file \
        imagemagick

COPY --from=ffmpeg /usr/local /usr/local

WORKDIR /
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev postgresql-libs postgresql-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc g++ build-base linux-headers \
    ca-certificates python3-dev libffi-dev libressl-dev && \
    ln -s /usr/include/local.h /usr/include/xlocale.h && \
    apk add py-numpy && \
    pip install pip --upgrade && \
    pip install numpy && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    apk --purge del .build-deps
RUN rm requirements.txt

COPY ./docker/imagemagick.policy.xml etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

COPY . .

# Run celery.py when the container launches
CMD ["celery", "worker", "-A", "a.celery", "--loglevel=info"]
```

Comment: Are you running the container on Google Cloud Platform? Your Local Server? AWS?

Comment: Both locally and on the server. In neither case does this work.

Comment: What permissions do you have for your bucket? try adding allUsers with Object Viewer role